# Making different and distinguishable random colors in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, random, colors

I want to make up to 100 different and distinguishable random colors in my winforms project. The method will executes in a loop as my desired times. I know how to make just random colors, but is there any Idea how to make different and distinguishable random colors, that a user by looking it could easily see the differences and recognize them?

My code:

```
private System.Drawing.Color RandomColor()
    {
         Random rand = new Random();
         int max = byte.MaxValue + 1; // 256
         int r = rand.Next(max);
         int g = rand.Next(max);
         int b = rand.Next(max);
         System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
         return color;
   }

   for(int i=0; i<100 or lesss; i++)
   {
      var randomColor = RandomColor();
      //I use randomColor to draw a thin line on my form.
   }
```

Comment: why should they be random in the first place? Why not just use a static set of colours?

Comment: set max to a n-times lower value, and multiply the results by n! just make sure to avoid duplicates, which is missing from you code as it is now..! or pick a random one from the NamesColors collection!

Comment: Maybe it is crazy typing them MakePeaceGreatAgain. I should also check static colors to see if they are different or not first I think.

Comment: n factorial you meant TaW?

Comment: I think these are enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.knowncolor

Comment: What makes you think a user can recognize 100 distinct colours? I don't mean distinguish - that is possible by far - but recognize them?

Comment: A truly random color also might not be distinguishable from your BACKGROUND color as well...

Comment: Distinguishing colors is not nearly as straightforward as you seem to think. [Colorblind people see colors differently](https://davidmathlogic.com/colorblind/#%23D81B60-%231E88E5-%23FFC107-%23004D40), and there are multiple types and degrees of colorblindness.